# median doesn't work after group_by in r function

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, median

I wrote a r function to compute the median by group:

```
varA<-rep(c(1:2),times=30)
df1<-data.frame(varA)
df1$var1 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$varA))
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(outcome=ifelse(varA==1, "Yes", "No"))

ctn_me<- function(df, var, group_var) {
  df[[group_var]]<-as.character(df[[group_var]])
  # df[[var]]<-as.numeric(df[[var]])
  tbl1<-df %>%
    bind_rows(mutate(., !!group_var := 'Total')) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(gpvar=.[[group_var]])%>%
    dplyr::summarise(
      median=median(.[[var]], na.rm = TRUE), 
      N = n())
  print(tbl1)
}

ctn_me(df1, "var1", "outcome")
```

It gave me results like this:

```
#### gpvar median   N
#### <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#### 1 No       734    30
#### 2 Total    734    60
#### 3 Yes      734    30
```

So it can count the number of rows within each group, but for the median, it returned the overall median instead by the group.

This gave me the results I wanted:

```
df1 %>% bind_rows(mutate(., outcome := 'Total')) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(outcome)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    median=median(var1, na.rm = TRUE), 
    N = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   outcome median     N
#   <chr>    <dbl> <int>
# 1 No        713     30
# 2 Total     734     60
# 3 Yes       788.    30
```

I was trying to figure out what was wrong with my r function. Can anyone let me know? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) state that you need to specifically reference ".data" within the `summarise()` function:

> "When you have an env-variable that is a character vector, you need to
> index into the .data pronoun with [[, like summarise(df, mean =
> mean(.data[[var]]))."

In this case, you need to change .[[variable]] to .data[[variable]], i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
varA<-rep(c(1:2),times=30)
df1<-data.frame(varA)
df1$var1 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$varA))
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(outcome=ifelse(varA==1, "Yes", "No"))

ctn_me <- function(df, var, group_var) {
  df %>%
    bind_rows(mutate(., !!group_var := "Total")) %>%
    group_by(gpvar = .[[group_var]]) %>%
    summarise(
      median_group = median(.data[[var]], na.rm = TRUE), 
      N = n()
      )
}

ctn_me(df1, "var1", "outcome")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   gpvar median_group     N
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#> 1 No            740.    30
#> 2 Total         754     60
#> 3 Yes           776.    30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Original answer:
If you use a different syntax inside the `summarise()` function it works as expected, so I think it's something to do with the `summarise()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
varA<-rep(c(1:2),times=30)
df1<-data.frame(varA)
df1$var1 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$varA))
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(outcome=ifelse(varA==1, "Yes", "No"))

ctn_me <- function(df, var, group_var) {
  df %>%
    bind_rows(mutate(., !!group_var := "Total")) %>%
    group_by(gpvar = .[[group_var]]) %>%
    summarise(
      median_group = median(!!sym(var), na.rm = TRUE), 
      N = n()
      )
}

ctn_me(df1, "var1", "outcome")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   gpvar median_group     N
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#> 1 No            740.    30
#> 2 Total         754     60
#> 3 Yes           776.    30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try this for non-standard evaluation.

````
ctn_me<- function(df, var, group_var) {
    df[[group_var]]<-as.character(df[[group_var]])
    # df[[var]]<-as.numeric(df[[var]])
    tbl1<-df %>%
        bind_rows(mutate(., !!group_var := 'Total')) %>%
        dplyr::group_by(.data[[group_var]])%>%
        dplyr::summarise(
            median=median(.data[[var]], na.rm = TRUE), 
            N = n())
    print(tbl1)
}```
````